# How to create and search through a list or array in command line

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line, command-prompt

I have a directory called ‘dir1’ located via the path ‘O:/dir1’ with multiple ‘subdir’ in it. I want to iterate over all of the ‘subdir’ names, save them in a list, and see if they are in ‘Y:/dir2’.

So far all I could figure out was:
    for /F %%i in (‘dir /b’) do ( something????)

Please help!

Comment: What is the theoretical 'something' that you want to do if the directory exists/doesn't exist?

Comment: You will probably find [SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/) to be a useful reference site; for this particular question, you should look at what they have to say about [`DIR`](https://ss64.com/nt/dir.html), [`FOR`](https://ss64.com/nt/for.html), and [variable expansion](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html).

Comment: You can use `FOR /D /R` to iterate through a directory tree.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin if the subdir exists in dir2, there would be a file in it called ‘file1’ which I would pull information from, and if it doesn’t exist, the loop would exit